# rsyslog with redis => ELK is not showing any logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, rsyslog

I am really new to the ELK stack, any help will be appreciated.

The idea was to have:

```
rsyslog server -> redis -> ELK stack
```

by following this recipe: https://sematext.com/blog/recipe-rsyslog-redis-logstash/

I can see the traffic go all the way to Elasticsearch, but have not been able to debug Elasticsearch yet. I believe that traffic should be going there because tcpdump shows it.

If I go to "Stack monitoring", Logstash is not showing up there. When going deeper, it does say that the "[Logstash node has been detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8KvY.png)", and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Kibana is not automatically showing logs in the Observability/Stream.

On the top of the page there is [a link to settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s9Ml.png) where you should choose
log index pattern that you have created.
A little unintuitive considering having that massive screaming button to add integrations.